# Symfony2 forms are rendered empty

Tags: forms, symfony, render

I've just started trying to build forms with Symfony2.4.2 and having a VERY frustrating time.  I have successfully managed to build the example found in the book chapter 12.  I've also tried to build essentially the same form in another project, in another bundle and always seems to end up with an empty form:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form"> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code to create this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use DMV\form3Bundle\Entity\Task;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
        $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('task', 'text')
            ->add('dueDate', 'date')
            ->add('save', 'submit')
            ->getForm();

        return $this->render('DMVform3Bundle:Default:new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),));

    }
}
```

new.html.twig:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

I've tried tried delving into the "$form" at a breakpoint at the "return $this->render..." line that is suppose to render the form and I DO see the form elements texts in the structure but it is a very large and complex structure and I'm not sure what I should see exactly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your new.html.twig template look like?

Comment: What version of Symfony do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply render form in your `new.html.twig` template like:

```
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}

{{ form(form) }}
```

But if you use Symfony version < **2.3**, so try to use something that:

```
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}
<form action="{{ path('task_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Victor.  That is what my twig file looks like. --- Mike

Comment: What version of Symfony do you use?